# Amazon account linking using firebase authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, alexa-skills-kit

Is there any option to implement amazon account linking using firebase,
We know we can implement account linking for google, facebook and twitter using firebase auth provider.

I am implementing account linking for google, twitter, facebook using firebase auth. The below code shows

```
firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider()
firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider()
```

then i am getting result using

```
firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider)
firebase.auth().getRedirectResult()
```

I want to link account using amazon login page.Is there any way to do it or please provide any suggestion to show amazon login page then user enter email and password i want to get user data

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Authentication has no built-in provider for Amazon sign-in. That means that, to allow signing in to Firebase with Amazon accounts, you'll have to create a custom provider.

Linking custom provider accounts into existing accounts (from built-in providers) is not currently supported. But if you look at [this Github thread](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/custom-auth-samples/issues/10), there's some good info on how to accomplish the same by using custom claims or another mechanism.