# Is it possible to user Snapchat Kit Login with Firebase?

Tags: firebase, oauth, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, snapchat

Is it possible to user Snapchat Kit Login with Firebase? I saw that they support Facebook, Google, Twitter and Github, but would it be also possible to do it with Snapchat since they released their Kit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no provider for signing in with Snapchat built into Firebase Authentication.

But you can add any provider you want with Firebase Authentication by implementing a [custom provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth) for them. To do this, follow the steps outlined in:

- [Is it possible to use additional providers for firebase authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61156964/is-it-possible-to-use-additional-providers-for-firebase-authentication/61158108#61158108)
- [How to use Firebase Authentication with Okta?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61037385/how-to-use-firebase-authentication-with-okta/61037431#61037431)
- [Amazon account linking using firebase authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58060748/amazon-account-linking-using-firebase-authentication/58060841#58060841)